# What does it mean to qualify a statement or argument

Tags: meaning

What does it mean by a statement being contestable? - (qualify a statement).

Comment: Easily, sometimes.

Comment: Perhaps it can sometimes be easily done.

Comment: I'm unsure what is being asked here.  The title "What does it mean to qualify a statement or argument?" asks a fairly straightforward question about what qualifying a statement means.  The posted question itself, "How do you make a statement in writing so it is contestable? - (qualify a statement)" appears to be a how-to question.  Which is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An unqualified statement is clear and unequivocal. A qualified statement expresses some level of uncertainty about its own accuracy. An example of the first kind would be:

*I can answer this question.*

An example of the second kind (a qualified statement) would be:

*If I am understanding this question correctly, I can answer it.*

The qualification indicates that if I am not understanding the question correctly, then I am not able to answer it.